# GLIBC version mismatch between my build and my target hosts

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling, glibc, beagleboneblack

I work with a beaglebone board (but probably it's not so important on which board)
it has linux-4.9.82-ti-r102 kernel version installed and I can't change it.
I created a code [image] 
, and tried to run it on the beagle 
(steps: I compiled with `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -ggdb user.c -o user` and then forwarded to beagle with `scp user debian@192.168.7.2:/home/debian`, on beagle I tried to run user `./user`)

but I got an error[image]
GLIB versions on the BeagleBone
[image] 
GLIB versions on my PC
[image] 
what should I do, I can’t update the beagle because I need exactly the linux-4.9.82-ti-r102
can I somehow change the versions of GLIBC (like in gcc
`sudo update-alternatives --config gcc`) or whatever

Answer (score 0):

> what should I do

Your `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` targets GLIBC-2.34 (or later) and is *not appropriate* for your (older) target.

You must either use a different (older) SDK which targets the version of GLIBC-2.24 on your target, or you must update your target with newer GLIBC.

> I can’t update the beagle because I need exactly the linux-4.9.82-ti-r102

The kernel version is *irrelevant* here. It's the version of GLIBC that you care about.

> GLIB versions on my PC

1. It's not GLIB, it's GLIBC
2. It's also irrelevant -- you are not using *host* GLIBC when you are building for target (look in the SDK directory for `libc-2.xx.so` to find out which GLIBC is actually used at build time).

Comment: is it possible to use `patchelf`?  I compile the program on my computer and transfer the binary code to the beagle. I understand that when compiling, host GLIBC is used.
I'm new and I don't understand what I have to do with the SDK.
p.s. thank you very much for your kindness

Comment: @Yael "I understand that when compiling, host GLIBC is used" -- no, _it's not_ (as I already said). "I don't understand what I have to do with the SDK" -- you need to find _appropriate_ SDK -- one which targets your desired OS and GLIBC -- the one which is running on the beagle.

Comment: can I get another binary which requires GLIBC-2.24?